# How to find pixel co-ordinates of corners of a square pattern?

Tags: language-agnostic, image-processing, opencv, camera-calibration

This may not be a programming related but possibly programmers would be in the best position to answer it.

For camera calibration I have a 8 x 8 square pattern printed on sheet of paper. I have to manually enter these co-ordinates into a text file. The software would then pick it up from there and compute the calibration parameters.

Is there a script or some software that I can run on these images and get the pixel co-ordinates of the 4 corners of each of the 64 squares?

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this with a traditional chessboard pattern (i.e. black and white squares with no gaps) using `cvFindChessboardCorners()`. You can read more about the function in the [OpenCV API Reference](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/camera_calibration_and_3d_reconstruction.html#findchessboardcorners) and see some sample code in [O'Reilly's OpenCV Book](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596516130) or [elsewhere online](http://www.aishack.in/2010/07/calibrating-undistorting-with-opencv-in-c-oh-yeah/). As an added bonus, OpenCV has built-in functions that calculate the intrinsic parameters of the camera and an array of extrinsic parameters for the multiple views of a planar calibration object.

Comment: Thanks for the OpenCV reference, I'm not sure if OpenCv can decode this pattern(I might be wrong here), I saw some other pattern on their calibration page.

Comment: All of the standard calibration routines that I know of (OpenCV and otherwise) assume a black-and-white "chessboard" pattern with no gaps between the squares. If you are not restricted to using the calibration pattern that you posted, I would strongly suggest using such a pattern. If this is not an option, you're going to have to write the corner detection code yourself (as described by user531627).

Answer (score 2):

I would:

- apply threshold and get binarized image.
- apply *SobelX* filter to image. You get an image with the vertical lines. This belong to the sides of the squares that are almost vertical. Keep this as **image1**.
- apply *SobelY* filter to image. You get an image with the horizontal lines. This belong to the sides of the squares that are almost horizontal. Keep this as **image2**.
- make (**image1** *xor* **image2**). You get a black image with white pixels indicating the corner positions.

Hope it helps.

Comment: And how do I do all this, I mean in which framework can I do this?

Comment: I would use, as Michael Koval suggested, OpenCV (http://sourceforge.net/projects/opencvlibrary/).

Comment: Anyway you could do a quick test by yourself. Just build an image. Suppose the image is a grid. [0,0] [1,0]... Take the first row and make Image1[0,0]=SrcImage[1,0]-SrcImage[0,0] and so on till the end of the image. So you get an output image which pixel values are equal to the the difference between the corresponding pixel and the immediate neighbour. This way

Comment: we get something like a horizontal derivative. It reveals zones where the constrast changes suddenly (square sides) in the horizontal direction. It's an easy/quick approximation to SobelX.

Comment: Any way I can check it in say Paint.Net or some image processing sofware.

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure there are many computer vision libraries with varying capabilities and licenses out there, but one that I can remember off the top of my head is [ARToolKit](http://www.hitl.washington.edu/artoolkit/), which should be able to recognize this pattern. And if that's not possible, it comes with a set of very good patterns that are tailored so that they can be recognized even if they're partially obscured.

Comment: Thanks! will check ARToolKit out!!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know ARToolKit (although i've heard a lot about it) but with OpenCV this processing is trivial.